# Initialize and invoke properties of objects in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a simple class in TypeScript that looks like:

```
class RandomHistory {
  randomNumberArray: any[] = [];
  ...
}
```

And an instance of an array of `RandomHistory` initialized like:

```
randomHistoryData: RandomHistory[] = [];
```

Now, inside a `forEach` I am trying to push new values into the `randomNumberArray` of a `RandomHistory` Object.
The code looks like:

```
result.data.forEach(function(el) {
   let randomHistory: RandomHistory = {
      randomNumberArray = []
   };
   for (let i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
      randomHistory.randomNumberArray.push(el.randomNumber.charAt(i));
   };
   this.randomHistoryData.push(randomHistory);
});
```

But getting errs as:

> Cannot find name 'randomNumberArray'.

and

> '=' can only be used in an object literal property inside a
>   destructuring assignment

which point to the lines:

```
let randomHistory: RandomHistory = {
    randomNumberArray = []
};
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you are using an object literal the syntax is `{key: value}` not `{key = value}`, so you want to do `{randomNumberArray: []}`.  Keep in mind that such an object literal will not be an instance of the `RandomHistory` *class* at runtime, even though TypeScript sees it as the same *type*.  If you want an actual class you should probably do `new RandomHistory` instead of trying to use an object literal.

Comment: why can't I use the object literal syntax here to instantiate a new `RandomHistory`?

Comment: Because to get an instance of a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) you should use its constructor.  An object literal gets the `Object` constructor, not the `RandomHistory` constructor.

Comment: Ah, makes sense